# How to format data using sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table called "Customer" like below

```
ID         NAME
1001       MATHEW
1002       THOMAS
1003       ALEX
1004       ALBY
```

I need to see output something like array like below in a single colum using sql query

out put like below

```
FORMAT_DATA
1001:MATHEW|1002:THOMAS|1003:ALEX|1004:ALBY|
```

How i do this in sl query

Comment: Did you need all in one row, or would "select id + ':' + name from Customer" work for you?

Comment: Why do you need it in a single column? To me, it sounds like you might be solving the wrong problem. If you need to have you consider writing a script that performs your query and then formats it as desired?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use FOR XML

**Query**:

```
select
(
  select RIGHT(ID,10) + ':' + NAME + '|'
  from Customer
   for xml path(''), type
).value('.','nvarchar(max)') DATA_FORMAT;
```

**Data**:

```
CREATE TABLE Customer (
    ID int, NAME varchar(20));
INSERT Customer VALUES
    (1001,       'MATHEW'),
    (1002,       'THOMAS'),
    (1003,       'ALEX'),
    (1004,       'ALBY');
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/563a6/3/0)**:

```
|                                  DATA_FORMAT |
------------------------------------------------
| 1001:MATHEW|1002:THOMAS|1003:ALEX|1004:ALBY| |
```